Does the Rubik's cube group act freely on the set of reachable positions of the cube?
The question of whether the group of valid operations on Rubik's cube acts freely (and therefore simply transitively) on the set of all reachable positions came up in the comments to this answer to another question. It seems fairly obvious to me that the answer is positive, and the WP article on the group in question says in its lead:  "there is a one-to-one correspondence between each of the legal positions of the Rubik's Cube and the elements of$~G$". So I'm asking the question not so much because I want to know the answer, as to know whether a positive answer can be deduced easily from some property of the way this group and action are defined, and can be generalised to other similar cases.
For clarity I'll recall the definitions. Let $S$ be the set of the $48$ mobile small squares on the cube ($8$ along the border of each of the $6~$faces; including the centre squares of the faces is unnecessary since none of the operations move them, but such an inclusion would not alter the answer). Each basic move determines a permutation of$~S$, affecting the $8$ squares of one face and $12$ squares on adjacent faces; we consider only "quarter turn" moves to be basic, and each of these has cycle type $(4,4,4,4,4)$, and therefore order$~4$. There are $12$ basic moves ($2$ for each face) and $G$ is defined as the group of permutations generated by these basic moves.
An assignment of colours to each of the squares is map $S\to{C}$ where $C$ is a set of $6$ colours. (This includes many invalid ones, like those where colour the frequencies are not uniform, but we will restrict to reachable ones.) The group $G$ acts on the set $A=C^S$ of all colour assignments by permutations of the squares, defined as usual by $g\cdot a = (s\in{S}\mapsto a(g^{-1}(s))$ for $g\in{G}$ and $a\in{A}$. The initial state $x_0\in{A}$ is the assignment that assigns to each square$~s$ the colour corresponding to the face to which $s$ belongs. The set of (reachable) states is defined as the orbit $G\cdot x_0$ of the initial state under the action of$~G$ on $A$. The action that this question is about, is the restricted action of $G$ on the orbit $X$, which by construction is transitive; the question is whether it is also free.
[One thing these definitions should make clear is that I am only considering differences that are visible using simple colouring of squares. There might be sequences of basic moves whose effect is to bring each square back to its original position but possibly with a non-trivial effect on the orientations of the centre squares of the faces, but such sequences define the identity element of $G$, and of course act trivially on $X$.]

An action of $G$ on $X$ is free if and only if the stabiliser subgroups of every $x\in{X}$ are trivial. Also stabiliser subgroups of elements of the same orbit are conjugate, and here there is by construction only one orbit, so it will suffice to show that the stabiliser of just one element is trivial; which I will do for the initial state $x_0\in{X}$. So it is to show that if for some $g\in{G}$ on has $g\cdot x_0=x_0$, then $g$ is the identity permutation.
From the definition of $G$ it is clear that its action on $S$ conserves the partition of $S$ into $8+12=20$ subsets corresponding to the pieces that can come off the cube if you take it apart: $8$ corner pieces (each giving a set of $3$ squares) and $12$ edge pieces (each giving a set of $2$ squares). Formally, there is an equivalence relation $\sim$ on$~x$ (with these sets as equivalence classes) such that $s\sim{t}\iff{g(s)}\sim{g(t)}$ for all $g\in{G}$ and all $s,t\in{S}$.
Now suppose $g\cdot{x_0}=x_0$; we want to show that $g(s)=s$, for all$~s$, so that $g$ is the identity permutation. Now $g\cdot{x_0}=x_0$ means that $g$ maps every $s\in{S}$ to a square on the same face of the cube as $s$ (namely, mapped to the same colour under$~x_0$, formally $x_0(s)=x_0(g(s))$). So fix some $s\in{S}$. Then because the action conserves the partition of $S$ according to the equivalence$~\sim$, the set of colours associated under $x_0$ to the set of ($3$ or $2$) squares equivalent to$~g(s)$ is the same as the set of colours associated under $x_0$ to the equivalence class of$~s$. But since each equivalence class of squares is characterised by it image under $x_0$ (in other words, each piece of the Rubik's cube has a unique set of colours on its faces), this means that $g(s)\sim{s}$, and since $g(s)$ is also on the same face of the cube while the other squares in the equivalence class of $s$ are on different faces, this implies $g(s)=s$, as desired.

Okay, thanks! Together with the fact that you're ignoring rotations of the centers I think that does it. So I think the point is each cubie is uniquely determined by the colors of its faces, even up to rotation. So if an element of the Rubik's cube fixes the solved state then it fixes both the position and orientation of every cubie except possibly the orientations of the centers, which we're ignoring, and so it acts trivially?

Let me try to vary the setup a bit so it's a little clearer what exactly is being used in the argument. Throughout we consider two states of the cube the same if they look the same. "Cubie" refers to one of the $20$ moving pieces of the cube, and "face" refers to one of the $3$ visible faces of the $8$ corner cubies or one of the $2$ visible faces of the $12$ edge cubies, so there are $3 \cdot 8 + 2 \cdot 12 = 48$ moving faces total. The centers don't move so we mostly don't consider them in the argument. Write $G$ for the Rubik's cube group.

At one extreme, clearly the action is not free if each face is the same color, since in this case there is only one state. The action is still not free if, say, two opposite $3 \times 3$ faces are painted red and blue, and the other faces are painted white, since we can freely rotate both the red and blue $3 \times 3$ faces.

At the other extreme, clearly the action is free if each face has a unique color. This is because an element of $G$ is determined by what it does to each cubie (including keeping track of the orientation of each cubie), and uniquely coloring the faces allows us to see the orientation of each cubie (including the centers, which don't move and whose orientations we are ignoring). We can think of this in terms of embedding $G$ as a subgroup of the "illegal Rubik's cube group" $G_I$, which is the group where you allow yourself to freely take apart the cube and put it back together again, meaning you can arbitrarily permute and reorient the $8$ corner cubies, and arbitrarily permute and reorient the $12$ edge cubies; if the faces have unique colors, then $G_I$ also acts freely.

We can adapt the second argument to the actual cube: although the faces don't have unique colors on an actual Rubik's cube, each cubie is still uniquely determined by the colors of its faces, even up to orientation. This means if an element of $G$, or even $G_I$, fixes the solved state, then it fixes the position and orientation of each cubie, so it is the trivial element. So $G$, and even $G_I$, acts freely.


We can use $G_I$ to be clear about what exactly we're considering $G$ to be acting on. $G_I$ can freely permute the $8$ corner cubies and $12$ edge cubies, and if we fix the positions of these then each corner cubie can be in one of $3$ orientations related by a $120^{\circ}$ rotation, and each edge cubie can be in one of $2$ orientations related by a $180^{\circ}$ rotation. This means $G_I$ is exactly the group
$$G_I \cong (C_3 \wr S_8) \times (C_2 \wr S_{12})$$
of order $3^8 \times 8! \times 2^{12} \times 12!$, and $G$ is the "legal" subgroup consisting of permutations and reorientations which can be obtained by rotating the cube as usual. According to Wikipedia it looks like the index of $G$ in $G_I$ is $12$; I assume there's some nice argument for this.

Not at all relevant to the question, but the above description of $G_I$ implies it has a fairly nice $20$-dimensional matrix representation using generalized permutation matrices, which is defined over $\mathbb{F}_7$.

You probably haven't played with a 4x4x4 cube, because you got that part wrong, or are using a definition of illegal group that is larger than the taking apart and putting together definition. The edges pieces are unique and distinguishable, even those with matching colours, because they cannot be flipped in place unless you peel the stickers. This would be more obvious with for example a ball-shaped 4x4x4 puzzle. The real problem here is the identical centre pieces, not the seemingly identical edge pairs.

@Jaap: the action I had in mind wasn't flipping the edge cubies in place, it was swapping them. But maybe you're saying that also isn't possible, with the reference to a ball-shaped puzzle? I guess because they're connected differently to the center?

You can swap them, but they flip in doing so, so you can still distinguish them by which way around their two colours are. If you imagine a ball-shaped 4x4x4, the two edge pieces are more clearly not identical despite having the same two colours - they have their colours in the opposite order relative to the adjacent corner piece. They are distinguishable precisely because they cannot flip in place.
